# R teradata DBI:dbConnect() error: TimedOut: No response received when attempting to connect to the Teradata server

Tags: r, windows, odbc, teradata, dbconnect

I am going to ask and answer this question because I spent more time than I'd like to admit searching for a response and couldn't find one. I installed Teradata ODBC Driver 16.20. In the ODBC Data Source Administrator, I added a Data Source. I named it teradata, put in the name of the Teradata Server to connect to and my username and password for authentication. When I tried running  the following code in RStudio:

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                      "teradata")
```

I would get an error:

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: HY000: [Teradata][WSock32 DLL] (434) WSA E TimedOut: No response received when attempting to connect to the Teradata server
```

Comment: Did you validate that your ODBC DSN actually works?

Comment: Yes, I did and the connection worked. My solution is below.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, I needed to pass a `timeout` argument:

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                      "teradata",
                      timeout = 20)
```